# How to programmatically close other applications from my Blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, background

I need to develop an application that finds all the visible applications (foreground and/or background) and close as many as it can. I tried with the below code:

```
ApplicationPermissionsManager appPermissionsManager = ApplicationPermissionsManager.getInstance();

ApplicationPermissions appPermissions = appPermissionsManager.getApplicationPermissions();

if (ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW == appPermissions.getPermissio(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INPUT_SIMULATION)) {
try {
EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent pressKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN, ((char) Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE), 0);

EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent releaseKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent.KEY_UP, ((char) Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE), 0);

EventInjector.invokeEvent(pressKey);
EventInjector.invokeEvent(releaseKey);

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("\n\n >>>>>> Block App Excep Thread 6 : " + e.toString() + "\n");
}
}
```

But this didn't help much to solve the problem. Can anyone suggest what can I use to implement this?

Comment: Hello, i try ur code it's work fine in my application. What's problem you? first you check to forground application or not? You need to add timer task and check any application is on forground? than after call your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.exit(0);`.  I used it before and it works.

Comment: sorry i though that was a menu code , there is a good way to do that is to invloke a menu item to the system menu items , and give this item the abillity to close the app by using `System.exit(0);` sorry again

Answer (score 0):

I hv recently develop a demo for the same task.

I hv use the same code which u hv given here... Would you tell me in detail, on which part of ur code u r facing problem......or provide ur code here.

You can find more details on :
[link 1](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/global-event-listener-is-not-called-instantly-and-properly-on/m-p/1762841#M201781)

and on :
[link 2](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-pause-the-timer-thread/m-p/1752959#M201209)

I would recommend a continuously running Thread which would just 'sleep' for a second and then check... for the current foreground application, whether you want to block it or not. Probably Timer task will be increased the load on ur application.... If you use a thread, you can block/pause its processing easily until it closes the current foreground native application but it will be difficult in case of a TimerTask.

Comment: Hey Rajani, thanks for the information. I've already tried what you mentioned but my need is not to just close the foreground application. Theere are 2 parts in it:

1. when my app is running in foreground, it should not allow any other background app to run (either block/close).

2. my app is can be put to background for listening for notifications.

i did try almost all solutions posted here as well as other forums in addition to what I tried on my own but with no luck. 

problem is, when i use EventInjector and do as i mentioned above, it closes my own app instead of closing the other apps.